# Search results not working - mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql, search

Im pretty new to php and MySQL but im trying to run a query that will search a table in my database and bring back the results with certain columns from that entry.

e.g. search for postcode and bring back: name, address, contact number, postcode.

can anyone point me in the right direction of what im missing or where I went wrong.

here are the details below

Latest Update

Form

```
<td><form action="searchresults.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><strong>Find a Active Physio</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="100">Physio Reference</td>
      <td width="301"><input name="PhysioReference" type="text" id="PhysioReference" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name of Physio</td>
      <td><input name="Physio" type="text" id="Physio" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact Number</td>
      <td><input name="Number" type="text" id="Number" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td><input name="PhysiosAddress" type="text" id="PhysiosAddress" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Postcode</td>
      <td><input name="postcode" value="" type="text" id="postcode" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Physios Email</td>
      <td><input name="PhysiosEmail" type="text" id="PhysiosEmail" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </form></td>
```

search results

```
<?php

require_once('auth.php');

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Physio"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select database.
   mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

    if(!isset($_POST['postcode'])) {
  header ("location:index.php");
 }
 $search_sql="SELECT * FROM `Physio` WHERE Postcode like '%".$_POST['postcode']."%'";
 $search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
 $search_rs= mysql_num_rows($search_query) ;
 echo "<p> Results </p>" ;
 echo $_POST['{postcode'] ;
  if ($search_rs > 0)
   {
  echo "<p>".$search_rs['Postcode'] ."</p>" ;

   } else {
   echo "NO Results found";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: All `mysql_*()` functions are [**officially deprecated**](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) *(no longer supported/maintained)* and will be [**removed**](http://j.mp/11j2t6j) in the future. You should update your code using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure future functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you are not connectiong to database .

change this

```
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

to

```
 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

and fix what krish said .

**EDIT:**

try this

```
 <p> Results </p>
 <?php if ($search_rs= mysql_num_rows($search_query) !=0)
  {
 echo "<p>".$search_rs['postcode'] ."</p>" ;

 } else {
 echo "NO Results found";
 }
 ?>
```

the whole code should be like that

```
  require_once('auth.php');

   $host=""; // Host name 
   $username=""; // Mysql username
   $password=""; // Mysql password 
   $db_name=""; // Database name 
   $tbl_name="Physio"; // Table name 

   // Connect to server and select database.
   mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

    if(!isset($_POST['physiopostcode'])) {
      header ("location:index.php");
     }
     $search_sql="SELECT * FROM `Physio` WHERE Postcode like '%".$_POST['physiopostcode']."%'";
     $search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);
     $search_rs= mysql_num_rows($search_query) ;
     echo "<p> Results </p>" ;
  if ($search_rs > 0)
   {
  echo "<p>".$search_rs ."</p>" ;

   } else {
   echo "NO Results found";
   }
   ?>
```

EDIT2:

change your input to this one

```
  <input name="postcode" value="" type="text" id="postcode" />
```

currently

```
  <td>Postcode</td>
      <td><input name="postcode" value="" type="text" id="postcode" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
    </tr>
```

EDIT3:

you are misspelling the column name from table , Note that column names are case sensitive with Big letter or small letters.

change this: `$search_rs['postcode']`  to `$search_rs`

Comment: I don't think there's a difference with this change.  `$host === "$host"` since double quotes parse the string, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Straight from phpmyadmin
Reference, Name, Line1, Line2, Line3, Line4, Line5, Postcode, Tel, Mobile, Fax, Email

Comment: ok I have done that and it now just says results and nothing else. do you want me to show you what I have in the code again?#

Comment: @echo_Me I have updated the original post with the most up to date code

Comment: not sure if i did it wrong originally but someone asked me to use mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_num_rows and it worked. i just want to get my results into a table now. thanks you

Comment: i just tried the edit and that brought up how many result there was in total

Comment: yes that worked perfect , that what mysql_num_rows do :) , if counts all num results , if you want fetch by columns then use mysql_fetch_array :) . ok glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_query()` instead of `mysql_quesry()`

Try this,

```
$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link)or die("cannot select DB");

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM `Physio` WHERE Postcode like '%".$_POST['physiopostcode']."%'";
$search_query=mysql_query ($search_sql);

?>
<p> Results </p>
<?php 
if (mysql_num_rows($search_query)>0) {
    while($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)){
        //your code here
    }
} else {
    echo "NO Results found";
}
```

Comment: this fixed the issue but its not finding any results, even though there should be.... Thanks for the sharp eye on the spelling mistake

Comment: it looks like the code is working but it isn't finding any results. I know there are result for the search. am I using the wrong field or anything from my form?

Answer (score -1):

A better way of doing this would be to use stored procedures and escaping your POST.

```
$connection= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pw","database") or die(mysqli_error("error connecting to database")); 
$postcode = htmlentities($_POST['physiopostcode']);   // Remove HTML tags from user entry
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Physio WHERE Postcode = ?"; // ? is our placeholder
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $postcode);  // Give our placeholder our user entered value
$stmt->execute();                   // Execute MySQL query
$result = $stmt->get_result();      // Grab results
if (isset($result)) {               // Print results (if any)
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['address'];
        echo $row['contactnumber'];
        echo $row['postcode'];
    }
} else {
echo "NO Results found";
};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have just tried this and  it didn't work I replaced the credentials at the top, but just comes up with page cannot be displayed

Comment: That's strange, the code is working for me.. See http://collabedit.com/yhjch - don't forget to edit the connection details in your code, and change all the references to database columns in the code to match your columns in your database exactly.

Comment: I changed the details to mine but no luck, do you want me to show you the code on that link you sent me?

Comment: @user3301611 Is it giving you an error? Did you remember to change all the fields from the while loop to match yours in database?

Comment: I will try it now, I have updated the code on the original post, in case you wanted to look if the form part is correct.

Comment: I have tried this and does not work, say page cannot be displayed... do you want me to copy it into the collaboration?

Comment: @user3301611 you can, although this sounds very strange. The code in my answer is working for me. Are you running wampserver, or how are you trying to view this file? Getting a 'page cannot be displayed' makes me wonder if your problem is much more simple than the code :P

Comment: im running a local ubunto web server. using filezilla to transfer the file and viewing it through IE. the other code that I changed in my original post works but does not list the results.